# How to Delete a CosmosDB Vertex using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

As we can read and write data into cosmosdb using pyspark as follws,

```
cfg = {
"spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : "xx:443/",
"spark.cosmos.accountKey" : "xx==",
"spark.cosmos.database" : "graphdb",
"spark.cosmos.container" : "graph" ,
"spark.cosmos.read.customQuery" : "select * FROM c where c.label =Email"
}

cosmosDbFormat = "cosmos.oltp"

df = spark.read.format("cosmos.oltp").options(**cfg).load()
```

Similarly is there a way tro delete the vertex using pyspark...

Please note the vertex wont be overwritten because its created using uuid.. So everytime a vertex which has a deletion in the original table, doesnt get removed..

Answer (score 0):

As from my knowledge, it is not possible to delete a vertex in cosmos DB using pyspark connector. You can [cosmos Spark connector to read from or write to cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-sql-api-spark). You can use the Azure data explorer by using the [.drop().](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/reference/#drop-step)

[Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin graph support and compatibility with TinkerPop features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support#:%7E:text=Supported%20Graph%20Objects%20%20%20%20Category%20,and%20deleti%20...%20%202%20more%20rows%20)